# ToListAsync() leads DbContext to crash using ef core

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I am writing a simple query to get all the data from a table in a .net core project. When using `ToListAsync()`, the process crashed without any exceptions thrown. And after changing to `ToList()`, the process run successfully. I am really curious about the reason behind.

The EF-Core version is 2.2.6.
The same method using `TolistAsync()`, failed.

```cs
public async Task<ICollection<TariffType>> GetAllTariffTypes()
{
    using(var dbContext = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(_appConfig.DbContextConnectionString))
    {
        var tariffTypes = await dbContext.TariffType.ToListAsync();

        return tariffTypes;
    }
}
```

The method using `ToList()`, it worked.

```cs
public ICollection<TariffType> GetAllTariffTypes()
{
    using(var dbContext = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(_appConfig.DbContextConnectionString))
    {
        var tariffTypes = dbContext.TariffType.ToList();

        return tariffTypes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in details : _"crashed without any exceptions thrown"_? May be you not `await GetAllTariffTypes`?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Thanks for replying. I do await GetAllTariffTypes. And the crash here means that after the process goes to line "await dbContext.TariffType.ToListAsync()", the whole process stops and exits automatically, not reaching the return line and no exceptions thrown.

Comment: So even with a try and catch, your proccess still exits?

Comment: @Twenty Yep, i tried adding catch block. But no exceptions thrown, so it never hit the catching part......

Comment: What is the  exit code of your application?

Comment: Try taking the first chunk of code out of the using block - maybe the using is disposing the dbContext before its finished? - In which case - I would expect an exception

Comment: @RobertPerry But he would get an `Can't access Disposed Object exception`, but even his try catch does not hit.